# How to best use 'based around your skill set' in a sentence most effectively?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, phrase-requests, sentence

I am trying to figure out which way I can convey the following sentence more convincingly.

> Get paid for providing hiring recommendations to hiring managers,
>   based around your skill set.

or

> Based around your skill set, Get paid for providing hiring
>   recommendations to hiring managers

or

> Get paid for providing hiring recommendations, around your skill set,
>   to hiring managers.

If there's any way to write this more concisely please advise.

Comment: Why are we helping you write spam?

Comment: ii am trying to figure the best way to get my message accross. In no way am i trying to spam

Comment: Isn't the idiom "base *on* your skill set"?  In which case "based around your skill set" suggests that you try some occupation other than writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence seems to me most grammatical. Though I believe "hiring" may be used redundantly. Consider "Based on your skill set, get paid for providing recommendations to hiring managers".

Comment: Thank you nicole. It make sense a lot of sense! Based around your suggestions, would this also work in terms of meaning and grammatical? Based on your skill set, get paid to provide insights to hiring managers.